# Scale Entire Site

Tags: html, css

I essentially want to be able to scale the entire site (images, elements, the whole sha-bang) to what ever browser size window the user is using. Anyone have success doing this and would be willing to share how?

I'm using HTML 5 by the way.

Comment: I suggest you research about responsive design. But the question in this form is rather general to answer here.

Comment: Haven't tried any I've been searching a for a solution for the past hour or so and haven't seen a decent one.

Comment: Responsive design through CSS media queries is a good place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start thinking about sizing your elements using percentages instead of pixels.

Take a look at this simple example and it may help you on your way. Good luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/hACbn/1/

Comment: Drag the result window to see it scale to different sizes.

Comment: Just for fun, I made a demo using javascript to show you can also scale the font size according to window width: http://jsfiddle.net/hACbn/5/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using responsive layouts:

Here's a half decent framework to get you started

http://gridpak.com/